# 50 Minute Layover In Casablanca Airport

Tags: layovers, short-connections, cmn

I've got a flight from Marrakech to Madrid, with a 50 minute layover in Casablanca. Also, I'll need to go from Terminal 1 to Terminal 2 in Casablanca. Is this enough time?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is less than the minimum connection time.

Comment: @MichaelHampton MCT D-I AT-AT is 40 minutes at CMN

Comment: It's worth noting: I made the connection, but I had no checked bags, and it was VERY close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This source](http://www.azworldairports.com/airports/a2120cmn.cfm) puts the "international-to-international" time in Mohammed V International Airport at 50 minutes.  Since you will also have to clear whatever exit formalities Morocco imposes, you probably won't make it.

And that is not even taking into account the time it will take to explain the whole story to Lazlo, kiss Ilsa goodbye, and shoot Major Strasser.

Comment: Yeah, but he'll always have Paris

Comment: @PeterM -- this could be the beginning of a beautiful friendship.

Comment: He also runs the risk of being considered a "usual suspect" at immigration and being referred to secondary.

Answer (score 1):

There is a three minutes walk between terminals. However going through police control might well take more than an hour, it's pretty nightmarish in Casablanca.

Comment: I don't know, but if you came from agadir to casablanca,  it's a domestic flight not requiring to go through control, unless I am mistaken

Comment: Then it's a short distance between the two terminals.